# I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?

Tags: discussion, merge

By using a further PC with a newly installed 16.04 Ubuntu, I accidentally created a new account - [user:1029634](https://askubuntu.com/users/1029634/tomas-peceny) and I need to merge it into my previous account [user:165175](https://askubuntu.com/users/165175/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-pe%C4%8Den%C3%BD). I have tried the [contact form](https://askubuntu.com/contact) (called from https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts), choosed 'I need to merge user profiles' and added the details and submitted; however I have obtained a response 'You may have contacted the wrong party. This email address provides support for the Q&A web sites at stackexchange.com, but we are not in a position to provide customer support for 3rd-party products or services, nor can we answer questions specific to certain technologies or topics. You will need to contact the correct support channels for help with your issue' from the Stack Overflow Team. They recommend me to ask at the https://askubuntu.com. How should I ask for such merging?
Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a case of misunderstanding. I'm not what you really wrote, but you can try being more specific and mentioning Ask Ubuntu (SE) accounts.

Comment: Did you use https://askubuntu.com/contact? Then it surely is a misunderstanding, this *is* the correct link.

Comment: Yes, I used it.

Comment: I can resend that mail, but I do not know at what mail address.

Comment: Now, I have signed in by the Firefox browser without stored personal data to check, if this comment from my "furtherPC" will be at the AskUbuntu recognized as from my previous user account 165175.

Comment: After the result of my last comment starting 'Now, I have signed in by the Firefox browser without stored personal data', this question about merging accounts is not so important for me. Before, I had not found, how to logout from the AskUbuntu, and did not want to use my passwords to the Google Chromium without my "furtherPC" being protected as I am used to.